# Formula for cos(k*x)

Tags: trigonometry, summation, induction

I need to prove that:
\begin{align}
c_k =&\; \cos(k\!\cdot\!x)\\
c_k :=&\; c_{k-1} +d_{k-1}\\
d_k :=&\; 2d_0\!\cdot\!c_k +d_{k−1}\\
d_0 :=&\; −2\!\cdot\!\sin^2{(x/2)}\\
\end{align}

I've got an explicit formula for $d_k$ which should be:

\begin{align}
d_k&=d_o+\sum_{i=1}^k{2\!\cdot\!d_o\!\cdot\!c_i} 
&&\implies&
c_k &=c_{k-1}+ \sum_{i=1}^k{2\!\cdot\!d_o\!\cdot\!c_i}
\end{align}

Now I want to do a proof by induction. Assuming that $c_p=\cos(p\!\cdot\!x)$ for every $p<k$.
This would get me the following:
$$c_k =\cos\left(\left(k-1\right)\!\cdot\!x\right)+\sum_{i=1}^k{2\!\cdot\!d_o\!\cdot\!\cos(p\!\cdot\!x)}$$
Using this formula I found:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx) & = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{nx}2\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}2\right)}\, \cos\left(\frac{(n+1)\,x}2\right)
\end{align}

I tried to play around with trigonometric addition formulas but I am getting nowhere.

Comment: Your $c_k$ coincide with $T_k(\cos x)$ where $T_k$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.

Comment: So the first line has to be proven, using lines 2-3-4? But then what is $c_0$?

Comment: @Justpassingby If $c_k=\cos(k*x)$, then $c_0=1$.

Comment: @XPenguen, just curious.  Should the $p$ and $i$ in the second to last formula be the same variable?  If not, what is $i$ in the summand?

Comment: @simpleArt if we are required to prove the relation that $c_k=\cos(k*x)$ then how can we use this relation and say $c_0=1$ and then use this ...to again prove the same thing that is $c_k=\cos(k*x)$ ...it is logically incorrect ...to use the information that we are required to prove ....

Comment: Very confusing. $c_k = \cos(kx)$ is the *definition* of $c_k$? Or you want to prove that is a consequence of the other conditions (with $c_0 = 1$)?

Comment: @XPenguen please mention in the question what condition we are required to prove ...and what information has been given... you have written all the four main equations in the beginning without clarifying this....as mentioned in some of the comments ..it is indeed making the question very confusing... Please edit the question and give the information given/ condition required to prove separately...

Comment: @SimpleArt: it is wrong to infer the value of $c_0$ from the answer. The OP must specify $c_0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP specifies $c_k=\cos(k*x)$, so $c_0=\cos(0)=1$, right?  Its near the top.  I think this is what the OP wants or something along those lines

Comment: @SimpleArt: the OP wants a proof by induction that $c_k=\cos(kx)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, good luck?  I do hope you manage it.

Comment: @SimpleArt: done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last equation reads
$$d_0=-2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)=\cos(x)-1.$$

Then eliminating $d$ from the second and the third,

$$d_k=c_{k+1}-c_k,\\
c_{k+1}-2c_k+c_{k-1}=2(\cos(x)-1)c_k.$$

If we assume that $c_k=\cos(kx)$, then after some simplification,

$$\cos(kx+k)-2\cos(kx)+\cos(kx-x)=2\cos(kx)\cos(x)-2\cos(kx)\\=2(\cos(x)-1)\cos(kx).$$

Hence $c_k=\cos(kx)$ is indeed a solution, such that $c_0=1$ (not specified in the OP).

We also have

$$d_k=\cos((k+1)x)-\cos(kx).$$

Now knowing these relations, formally proving by induction isn't a problem anymore.

---

By the induction hypothesis, $$c_{k-1}=\cos((k-1)x),\\d_{k-1}=\cos(kx)-\cos((k-1)x).$$

Then,

$$\color{green}{c_k}=c_{k-1}+d_{k-1}=\cos((k-1)x)+\cos(kx)-\cos((k-1)x)\color{green}{=\cos(kx)}$$
and
$$\color{green}{d_k}=2(\cos(x)-1)c_k+d_{k-1}\\
=2(\cos(x)-1)\cos(kx)+\cos(kx)-\cos((k-1)x)\\
=2\cos(x)\cos(kx)-2\cos(kx)+\cos(kx)-\cos(kx)\cos(x)-\sin(kx)\sin(x)\\
=\cos(kx)\cos(x)-\sin(kx)\sin(x)-\cos(kx)\\
\color{green}{=\cos((k+1)x)-\cos(kx)}.$$

And the base case is

$$\color{green}{c_0}=\cos(0\cdot x)=\color{green}{1},\\
\color{green}{d_0}=\cos(1\cdot x)-\cos(0\cdot x)=\color{green}{\cos(x)-1}.$$

Comment: Probably easier using $\cos((k+1)x)+\cos((k-1)x)=2\cos(kx)\cos(x)$.